# Expected value of number of successes of n independent experiments

Tags: probability, independence, means

Assume n independent experiments with probabilities of $p_1,...,p_n$. 
Let's define the random variable as this:

$$X=
\begin{cases}
\ 1,  & \text{if exactly 1 of n experiments was successful} \\2, & \text{if exactly 2 of n experiments were successful} \\\ ... \\\\ n,& \text{if exactly n of n experiments were successful} 
\end{cases}$$
Now the expected value (mean) of X would be:
$$E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^n X_iP(X_i)$$
This expected value would be equal to sum of $p_1,...,p_n$. In other words:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n X_iP(X_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i $$
Why the expected value is equal to sum of $p_1,...,p_n$? I'd be grateful if someone writes the mathematical proof coherently so I can use it in a scientific research.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to write "$P[X=i]$" rather than "$P[X_i]$," especially since we do not know what "$X_i$" is supposed to mean (if it is inside the $P[\cdot]$ function then it must be an *event*).  So, 
$$E[X] = \sum_{i=0}^n iP[X=i]$$

You can derive the desired result using *indicator functions* together with the fact that the expectation of a sum is the sum of expectations: Define
$$ Y_i  = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 &\mbox{ if experiment $i$ is successful} \\
0  & \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right. $$
Then 
$$X = Y_1 + Y_2 + ... + Y_n \implies E[X]=E[Y_1] + E[Y_2] + ... + E[Y_n]$$
But of course you can compute $E[Y_i]$ for each $i\in\{1, \ldots, n\}$ to get the desired result. Also, that result is true regardless of whether or not the experiments are independent.